# UiButton click doesnt work on UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, controller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIView which is added to Page View Controller.  This UIView have a multiple buttons which are tied to an action defined in the controller.  At runtime, these views get added to Page View Controller.  The problem i am seeing is after loading the page view controller, when i click on the first button.  It works fine.  But the rest two buttons doesn't.  I made sure that the User Interaction is enabled and it is linked to IBAction.  Don't know what is causing this issue.

Comment: Would you be able to add a screenshot if possible. When you click on the the second and third button is the action method called at all?

Answer (score 0):

UIButtons are usually unresponsive if their superview userInteractionEnabled property is set to NO or if they are outside of their superview's bounds. The fact that only two of the buttons are not working, makes me think that the latter is the cause of the issue. Set the background color of the superview, run the app and check that the buttons are within their superview's bounds. If they aren't, move them inside the bounds or increase the superview's frame size in order to fit them in.